# Auto populate the fields of a form by entering one ID field

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have two forms in my jsp page consider form1 and form2. form1 has ID latitude and longitude fields and a save button. form 2 has dataID date ID latitude and longitude fields. Once the form1 is saved in the database in a table. I need to enter the ID field in second form which should automatically populate latitude longitude fields from form1. How do I do this using jquery and ajax?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertData.jsp" action="post" >
DATA ID:<input type="text" name="data_id"><br>
East:<input type="text" name="east"><br>
North:<input type="text" name="north"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my first form. And is stored in a table.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertData.jsp" action="post" >
Some ID:<input type="text" name="some_id"><br>
date:<input type="text" name="date"><br>
DATA ID:<input type="text" name="data_id"><br>
East:<input type="text" name="east"><br>
North:<input type="text" name="north"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

This is my secon form wherein I want the fields namely east and North to be automatically filled after entering data id in the form. how do I auto populate those fields using the first form data

javascript code

```
var dataid = var _POST('dataid');

var host         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var user         = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
var password = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
var dbname   = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

var cxn = mysqli_connect( host, user, password, dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {alert( "No connection"  + "" +  mysqli_connect_error());}

var query = " SELECT * \
       FROM latlong \
       WHERE dataid = " + dataid + "";

var result = mysqli_query(cxn, query) OR  ("could not connect");

var json = {};
while (var row = mysqli_fetch_array(result))
{ 
 var bus = 
           {
            'dataid' : row['dataid'],
               'lat' : row['lat'],
              'long' : row['long']
            };
  array_push(json, bus);
}
alert( json_encode(json));
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so-far?

Comment: Whoever has given it a -1 please specify the reason. i hve not asked anything rong. If i have please specify what is rong?

Comment: @TimSPQR Sir i will put up the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Again, my apologies.

1. You need to make a php file that resides on your server so when you call it, it will return data to the client.

Here is a proposed file. It receives the dataid from a POST, and I'm not sure how you will post the dataid.

Then you need the client-side ajax call, proposal below the php file:

1. find a way to input the 'dataid'
2. pass it to the ajax call
3. parse the data that comes back with a .done function

   ```
   <? php

   $dataid = $_POST('dataid');

   $host         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $user         = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
   $password = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
   $dbname   = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

   $cxn = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $password, $dbname);
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

   $query = " SELECT * 
              FROM latlong 
              WHERE dataid = $dataid";

   $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not connect");

   $json = array();
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $bus = array
                  (
                   'dataid' => $row['dataid'],
                      'lat' => $row['lat'],
                     'long' => $row['long']
                   );
      array_push($json, $bus);
   }
   echo json_encode($json);
   ```

   ?>

   ```
   <input type='text' id='dataid' />
   <div id=latdiv></div>
   <div id=longdiv></div>

   $.ajax({
              url: 'nameofyourphpfile.php',
             type: POST,
             data: { dataid: dataid },
         dataType: 'json',
           })
             .done(function(result) {
                                     $('#latdiv').html( result.lat );
                                     $('#longdiv').html( result.long);
                                     });
   ```

If you are putting the data into an input field you need to use .val() not .html().

I don't know the details of your pages, but this will give you a start.

Comment: Right sir. thanks for the code and also for pointing out my mistake of not following rule :)

Comment: Sir if the forms are in 2 different pages and I save the first form data in database and later enter the dataid in second form which should give me the saved east and north values.The dataid in first form should match the dataid in second form then the corresponding east and west values should be rendered. how do I fix this?

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention two different pages. So you will save the data to the db on the first page. Then the user hits the second page, it will read the db and put the data into the input fields. Then the user can fillout the rest of the data, and the entire dataset is stored in the db as an 'update' of the row. You could also do it with cookies of session variables, but if the ultimate location is the db, then I'd just right it there from the beginning.

Comment: Sir yes i have created a table where it stores the first form data. for second form data i have created a table. But how can i read the first form table and render the data which corresponds to the dataid entered in the second form?

Comment: I apologize, I apologize, I'm an idiot. Now I understand your question. Today I'm going to spend some time revising my answer and assuming you are talking about two MySQL tables, and moving data between them. Again, I'm sorry. Give me an hour or so and I'll try to help.

Comment: Sir I have edited my question where i have used your php code to javascript. Is it right in javascript?

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue. PHP is a language that is "server-side" - the server runs the program everytime the client calls it, and the output of the PHP goes to the client. The client uses javascript to "grab" the data from the php program and present it to the user. Two different languages, two different places on the network. If you've never used php, then there will be a 1-2 month "learning curve". I suggest you get a book, or start reading about php on the web.

Comment: Yes sir I have never used php. Ok sir thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Sir can I not do it without using php? because I need this for my project wherein I am running short of time. I do not have time to learn php and then implement the same.

Comment: You say "stored in a table" - so you must be using some type of server language like php. What are you using to "store" data in a table?

Comment: Yes I use servlets sir

Comment: Ok, I've never used servlets before. You're going to have to read about which servlets return data from the server and how to parse it into the fields on your HTML.